# In the MVC, the handling events code should put in the controller or view?

Tags: model-view-controller, events, event-handling

if the user press the button, handling this event should put on controller or event? Thanks.

Comment: Please provide more information with this question, especially what platform (Web, Desktop) and what development framework Java, .NET, etc.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends of the platform you are working on, because there are huge differences with desktop development (like .NET's WinForms / WPF or Java's Swing versus ASP.NET and Java Servlets or PHP, for example).

In desktop programming the event system makes it really easy (and sometimes even natural, depending how you look at it) to do a lot of the work in the event itself, but eventually you'll find yourself coding A LOT of the program's logic there, making your view a mess. In web programming this is harder to do because you can't really to much of the system logic in the browser (you can't open a connection to the database, you don't have access to the session or any other kind of information that wasn't previously make available by the server).

Also, it is much easier to apply MVC in Web development because of the nature of how the requests and responses work. On the other hand, when programming to Desktop everything is right there at your need, you can easily access any control from probably everywhere, and even if you don't, you will think it is OK (even when it's not) to share things using static variables (or a lot of singletons).

To make a long story short, I'd say that you should make all necessary efforts to resume logic programmin in the events as possible. With some practice, you will discover that delegating the logic to a regular object instead of the view itself will make your life easier in the long shot.

In time: the kind of controller that you use could be important too. For example, ASP.NET uses some kind of Page Controller, while many PHP and Java frameworks are more kind to use a FrontController (it's not a rule of course, but can make a difference of how you see things).

Comment: I am doing desktop application development. So, you mean that the desktop application development event handling should put n view?

Comment: I agree with the point that this question needs to be improved to include the platform.

Comment: Ted, in a nutshell what I am saying is that the basic event handling will be started in the view just because this is how the frameworks will enforce you, but the logic itself should be put as much as possible in separated "business classes", that should know as less as possible about the view (you can pass references, for example).